# Android Recylcerview set Position of Item programmatically

Tags: java, android

i created a recylcerview for myChats. In this Recyclerview i can see a thumb, the last message and the name. if i send or receive a new message the item should go to first position, like in whatsapp.  to receive the new message i created the following method:

```
 private void getLastMSG(final String userId, final TextView lastMSG){
    String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("connections").child("matches").child(userId);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String lastMsg = dataSnapshot.child("lastMsg").getValue().toString();
                    lastMSG.setText(lastMsg);



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Now i want to set this item to first position but i dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call:

`notifyItemMoved(oldPos, newPos)` in your `recyclerview` adapter. 
Note that you need to update your data model before that, in order to bind correct view in `onBindViewHolder` method.

[Referece to adapter documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemmoved).

Comment: what do you mean with updating my data model?#

Comment: Your data model should be list of `Items` that you talked in the post.